# How long does reverse DNS take to propagate?

Tags: dns, rdns

Say I have two domains, `foo.com` and `bar.com`, and I initially have an A record for:

> www.foo.com → 1.2.3.4

I then decide I want `www.bar.com` to resolve to this IP, so I delete `www.foo.com`'s A record, and add an A record for `bar`:

> www.bar.com → 1.2.3.4

This looks fine via `dig`.  However, when I do a reverse DNS lookup on that IP, I still see `www.foo.com`.

Any idea how long reverse DNS takes to propagate?

Comment: DNS does NOT propagate!  Records are cached, the TTL controls the caching.  cache!=propagation

Comment: fair enough. i think you get my point though.

Comment: As I understand it, cache is the active records being stored by each DNS server, and propagation is the process (and time) it takes for the new instructions to get to all the necessary DNS servers, usually across a broader network (such as the internet). They're not the same thing, and they're not both the problem in each case (especially with DNS servers on a local network).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propagation depends on the TTL set for the DNS hosts involved and may also be hindered by local caching on your client. Also, depending on how you're making your changes, you may have to independently enter the reverse entry.

Comment: Most of the time you need to do an RDNS entry manually, or have whoever hosts the DNS to do it.

Comment: Thanks -- the TTL on the original entries were 3600, so after >24 hours I would have expected it to be fully expired. I'm using Amazon route 53 for DNS, I'll look to see if they have a way to edit RDNS entries.

Comment: -1 DNS does not propagate.

Answer (score 4):

This is *nothing* to do with the mythical idea of "DNS propagation".  As `Zoredache` has quite rightly said, this is an erroneous concept (based, if it is based upon anything at all, upon the long-since-altered behaviour of some domain name registries).  The DNS does not work that way.  Your data were available from your content DNS servers to the world *as soon as you entered them*.

This is everything to do with the fact that you have name→address conflated with address→name.  You've entered a name→address mapping but you've expected that to magically affect the lookup of an address→name mapping.  You're spending days at a time waiting for things to "propagate" when you haven't in fact enacted any changes to the relevant data in the first place.

If you want to look up the new name→address mapping that you've just entered, **look up the domain name**.  If you want to change what an address→name lookup returns, **change the address→name mapping data in your database**.  [Address→name mappings](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-ptr-record/) do not involve either `A` or `AAAA` resource record sets.

Comment: This is ovely pedantic. "Propagation" is a perfectly reasonable description of the process of the DNS records on the many DNS servers across the internet updating to reflect changes. Of course, the actual problem you've pointed out is both unrelated to propagation, and completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is a propagation delay involved. When you change your "delegation" at your RIR for your reverse DNS to new servers, there is usually 24 hours for those reverse DNS name server changes to occur. However some people have waited longer......ARIN says that it usually takes 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think reverse DNS lookup is not based on A records but on PTR records, so if it doesn't change, it is maybe not because of propagation delays.

Comment: DNS records follow the same caching rules regardless of their type – both A and PTR records have a TTL, etc.

Comment: Sure, but on his question, Joe batista talks about changing A records and is expecting a change on PTR records !